# How to get data from an array using get_user_meta()

Tags: functions, user-meta

I have created a custom user profile field

```
<?php $basics = get_the_author_meta( 'fbasics', $user->ID ); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><input value="lesson1" name="fbasics[]" <?php if (is_array($basics)) { if (in_array("lesson1", $basics)) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } }?> type="checkbox" /> <?php _e('Lesson 1', 'gprofile'); ?></li>
        <li><input value="lesson2" name="fbasics[]" <?php if (is_array($basics)) { if (in_array("lesson2", $basics)) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } }?> type="checkbox" /> <?php _e('Lesson 2', 'gprofile'); ?></li>
    </ul>
```

I now need to use the data on the front end of wordpress to display information. I think I need to use the `get_user_meta()` function but I do not understand how to use is to get the value of an array.

How to get data from an array using `get_user_meta()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is `<?php get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);  ?>`

The `$single` is a *boolean* that returns a single value for true or an array if set to false, in your case you would set it to false.

```
$user_output =  get_user_meta($user_id, 'fbasics', false);
 var_dump($user_output);
```